# Support for secondary language in ASP.NET localization

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization

ASP.NET has build-in functionality to automatically load the correct language resource file based on the browser's preferred language.

For example, if a visitor has Danish (da) as his/her preferred language, and the website has a *.da.resx file, then that resource is used. When the preferred resource file is not available, ASP.NET falls back to the basic/default resource file (*.resx).

Now, browsers allow for more than one preferred languages to be specified. If the visitor would speak Danish, but added Norwegian as a second language to the browsers preferences (written Norwegian is 95% identical to Danish), then the browser would send "da,no;q=0.9" to the web server. However, it seems this secondary language is not supported by ASP.NET; *.no.resx will not be loaded if *.da.resx is not available.

Does anybody know how to support secondary languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that ASP.NET only automatically processes the first entry in the accept-languages header field to determine which culture to use if [`enableClientBasedCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.enableclientbasedculture.aspx) is enabled in the web.config file.

If you wish to extend this and examine other language entries (if any) in the accept-languages list to see if you have a match, you will have to do it programmatically and set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`(which the ResourceManager uses to find the appropriate localized resources) and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (which will control how locale-aware datatypes will be presented and processed). This is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Comment: How stupid, that ASP.NET, even with the 4th major release, doesn't support such basic functionality! I think I've even found a big bug, but I think I'll pose that as a separate question. Do you know of any alternatives to the build-in internationalization support?

Comment: Yes, I wonder why it's done this way, why only look at the first item in the list? Maybe they've found that most users (even in your scenario) aren't savvy enough to have that list set up correctly? That's just a guess. As an end user, you probably would expect to see a language selector somewhere on the site anyway. If you expose such a selector, then it's quite trivial to look at the accept-languages header and do the selection logic you wish (looking at all the languages listed) to choose the default language.